# USB not working in 14.04.1 (sometimes)

Tags: 14.04, usb, lenovo, touchscreen, yoga-2

About one out of three boots, USB doesn't work on my Lenovo Yoga 2 11 running Ubuntu 14.04.1. This includes the USB touchscreen as well as optical drive, keyboard, or anything else plugged into the USB ports. (External devices are receiving power, but Ubuntu cannot access them.)

At these times, "sudo lsusb" produces only:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux FOundation 2.0 root hub
```

It does not show the touchscreen or any other internal or external USB devices. "sudo lsusb -v" produces a longer, but still blank, list, accompanied by the error messages:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
[...]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

dmesg shows USB starting within 1-2 sec of boot, then around 35-55 sec it starts generating errors and disconnects, e.g.

```
[ 37.585681 ] usb 2-5: device not accepting address 6, error -108
[ ... ]
[ 52.597822 ] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 52.623080 ] usb 2-6: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 52.627232 ] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

Tinkering with BIOS settings didn't do anything, and my computer has the latest BIOS (AACN15WW) so there's nothing to update there. Updating Ubuntu didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to kernel 3.14.23 seems to have fixed the problem, so I am concluding that it is a kernel bug. I did find other similar reports, but can't track them down at the moment to cite here.